# Как вызвать модальное окно двойным кликом без JQuery?

Tags: bootstrap, typescript, angular2

Здравствуйте, я использую в своей задаче Angular2 и Twitter Bootstrap. Возник такой вопрос, можно ли как то вызвать модальное окно при двойном щелчке по текстовому полю без применения JQuery? Сколько не гуглил, поиск давал лишь с применением JQuery. Я поставил обработчик двойного клика. А в каком направлении двигаться дальше пока не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста...

Мой код:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input type="text" (dblclick)="eventEmitDoubleClick($event)"/>
    `,
})

export class ExampleComponent{
    @Output() eventEmitterDoubleClick = new EventEmitter();
    eventEmitDoubleClick(event) {
        this.eventEmitterDoubleClick.emit(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще Twitter Bootstrap предпологает обязательное использование JQuery:

> Plugin dependencies
>
> Some plugins and CSS components depend on other plugins. If you include plugins individually, make sure to check for these dependencies in the docs. Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included before the plugin files). Consult our bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

Так что подключать jQuery все равно надо. Если вы хотите чтобы ваш код не зависел от jQuery то можете воспользоваться например библиотекой [ng2-bs3-modal](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal).

Comment: Ну да я понимаю, что подключать все равно надо. Просто прочитал статейки и не хотелось бы лишний раз использовать JQuery
[http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0]
[http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/is-jquery-still-relevant]

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду использовать эту библиотеку

Comment: Указанная библиотека тоже опирается на jQuery как сказано [здесь](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal#dependencies)